# why USB sticks are invisible in NoviCorp wintoflash(windows software)

Tags: boot, usb, mount, wine

I am trying to create a boot-able windows 7 USB stick through WinToFlash in wine-tricks.But whenever i started wintoflash,USB drives are not showing.I did so many thing via g-parted,disks...formatting,deleting,mounting,UN-mounting,auto mount on start up the 4-GB,8-GB pen drive,but it is not showing in NoviCorp wintoflash.

Comment: Rufus also not showing any usb drives.i have wine  1.4,maybe i have to upgrade to 1.7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these instructions to format the disk as FAT32 (readable by Windows):

1. Click the dash and search 'Disks' and open it.
2. Click your memory stick on the left.
3. Look at the titlebar of the window, and write down the part that says `/dev/<something>`, e.g. `/dev/sdb`.
4. Open the terminal and run `sudo umount /dev/<something>*`, replacing  with your disk (make sure to keep `*`), e.g. `sudo umount /dev/sdb*`. Don't worry about any warnings.
5. Go back to Disks and click the menu button in the top right, and select `Format Disk`. Choose `Don't overwrite existing data` and `Compatible with all devices`.
6. Click on the free space and click the plus.
7. Choose `Don't overwrite...`, `Compatible with all systems...` and pick a name.
8. Confirm this; when done, you should see it there. If there's a triangle in the bottom right corner, click it.

Now, open Wine config from the dash. Go to the Drives settings and click the autodetect button - this should make it detect your USB stick. When done, restart the application and it should work.

Comment: thank you @David Bailey,,thank you thank you thank you soooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo much,,you are great (y)

Comment: :D did it work correctly?

Comment: yes yes yes yahooooooooooooooooooooooo